# Botão de copiar o que está na textarea no Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Estou tentando criar um botão que faça um <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> na `textarea`, com *javascript*, é possível fazer um `select()` no `document.getElementById`, e depois da um `document.execCommand('copy')`, porém como estou trabalhando com *Ionic*, desse maneira não funciona, como poderia ser feito isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Use o plugin `Clipboard`, veja abaixo:

#### Instalação

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-clipboard
npm install @ionic-native/clipboard
```

#### Inserir nos módulos

Adicione o `Clipboard` nos módulos do `AppModule`, veja abaixo:

```
import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard';

....

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
  providers: [Clipboard]
  ...
})

export class AppModule {}
```

#### Inserir na página

Por último insira na página, abaixo a função `onCopy` irá colocar o texto passado nela para área de transferência:

```
import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard';

export class Page {
    constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard) { }

    onCopy(text) {
        this.clipboard.copy(text);
    }

}
```

Comment: Funciona no ionic 3.9.2?

Comment: Quando eu utilizei era ainda na versão 3, provavelmente deve funcionar.

Comment: No ionic 4 diz que copy não faz parte do elemento

Comment: A biblioteca mudou, agora tem um /ngx no final. porém agora da esse erro: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Clipboard.copy (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:79857:124)

Answer (score -1):

Use o ionic v3 para desenvolvimento, a versão v4 ainda tem muitos bugs.
Ao instalar o Ionic use o caminho: **npm install ionic@4.8.0 -g​.**

Comment: estou usando o v3, dá na mesma